# Spring Boot DefaultListableBeanFactory Overriding bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, repository, entity

I have a Spring Boot server which a problem with a Repository.

This is my **Application.java**

```
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"palmaslab.mapas.repository","palmaslab.mapas.security.registration","palmaslab.mapas.persistence.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"palmaslab.mapas.repository","palmaslab.mapas.security.registration","palmaslab.mapas.persistence.dao"}/*.PostoSaudeRepository.class*/)
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"palmaslab.mapas.controller","palmaslab.mapas.security.registration","palmaslab.mapas.persistence.service","palmaslab.mapas.persistence.dao","palmaslab.mapas.persistence.model"})
@Import({palmaslab.mapas.security.SecurityConfiguration.class})
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({"application.properties","classpath:email.properties.sample"})

public class Application extends /*WebMvcConfigurerAdapter*/ RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration{



    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/**", "classpath:/resources/**", "classpath:/resources/static/img/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
         }

    @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
                DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
            lef.setPackagesToScan("palmaslab.mapas.repository","palmaslab.mapas.controller");

            return lef;
        } 


        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); //Auto creating scheme when true
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);//Database type
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        }
       }
```

I have several repositories located in different packages: `palmaslab.mapas.repository`, `palmaslab.mapas.security.registration`, `palmaslab.mapas.persistence.dao` and all of them are working ok except `ParametrosRepository` which is automatically the bean definition changed by the `DefaultListableBeanFactory`.

This is the **ParametrosRepository.java**

```
@Repository
    public  interface ParametrosRepository extends CrudRepository<Parametros,Long>{

    public Parametros findById(long id);
    public List<Parametros> findByIdproject(long id);

    public List<Parametros> findByIdprojectOrderBySortAsc(long id);
    public List<Parametros> findByIdprojectOrderByPointtypeAscSortAsc(long id);
    public List<Parametros> findByIdprojectAndPointtypeOrderBySortAsc(long id,long pt);
    public List<Parametros> findBySortAndPointtypeAndIdproject(long sort,long pointtype, long idproject);
}
```

Which has **Parametros Entity**:

```
@Entity(name = "parametros")
public class Parametros {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    List<String> rrespostas = new ArrayList<String>();



    @Size(max=1000)
    String pergunta;
    String title;
    String note;
    int type;
    int multi_minimum;
    int multi_maximum;

    long idproject;

    String extra_conf;

    long sort = 0;
    boolean photo = false;

    long pointtype = 0;

    public long getSort() {
        return sort;
    }


    public long getPointtype() {
        return pointtype;
    }



    public void setPointtype(long pointtype) {
        this.pointtype = pointtype;
    }



    public boolean isPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }



    public void setPhoto(boolean photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }



    public void setSort(long sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }



    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }



    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }



    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }



    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Parametros(){
        multi_minimum = 0;
        multi_maximum = 0;

    }



    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getExtra_conf() {
        return extra_conf;
    }



    public void setExtra_conf(String extra_conf) {
        this.extra_conf = extra_conf;
    }



    public int getMulti_minimum() {
        return multi_minimum;
    }



    public void setMulti_minimum(int multi_minimum) {
        this.multi_minimum = multi_minimum;
    }



    public int getMulti_maximum() {
        return multi_maximum;
    }



    public void setMulti_maximum(int multi_maximum) {
        this.multi_maximum = multi_maximum;
    }



    public void setIdproject(long idproject) {
        this.idproject = idproject;
    }



    public long getIdproject() {
        return idproject;
    }
    public void setId_project(long idproject) {
        this.idproject = idproject;
    }
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void addResposta(String resposta)
    {
        rrespostas.add(resposta);
    }
    public void removeResposta(int i)
    {
        rrespostas.remove(i);
    }
    public List<String> getRrespostas() {
        return rrespostas;
    }
    public void setRrespostas(List<String> rrespostas) {
        this.rrespostas = rrespostas;
    }
    public String getPergunta() {
        return pergunta;
    }
    public void setPergunta(String pergunta) {
        this.pergunta = pergunta;
    }
}
```

The `ParametrosRepository` is `@Autowired` in the **PalmapController**:

```
@Controller
public class PalMapController {

    @Autowired
    private ParametrosRepository parametrosRepo;

     [...]

 }
```

This is the **Error**:

```
2017-05-08 14:03:05.523  INFO 19384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.**DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'parametrosRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean];** scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-05-08 14:03:08.736  INFO 19384 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c89aadcd] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-08 14:03:10.166  INFO 19384 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 9876
2017-05-08 14:03:10.796  INFO 19384 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-08 14:03:10.805  INFO 19384 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
2017-05-08 14:03:11.052  INFO 19384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-08 14:03:11.053  INFO 19384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationConte  ....

[...]

2017-05-08 13:11:42.562 ERROR 1015 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.**BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'palMapController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private palmaslab.mapas.repository.ParametrosRepository palmaslab.mapas.controller.PalMapController.parametrosRepo**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [palmaslab.mapas.repository.ParametrosRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at palmaslab.mapas.config.Application.main(Application.java:81)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private palmaslab.mapas.repository.ParametrosRepository palmaslab.mapas.controller.PalMapController.parametrosRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [palmaslab.mapas.repository.ParametrosRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [palmaslab.mapas.repository.ParametrosRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

The remaining Repositories and Entities are working ok. Anyone knows why the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` is changing the `ParametrosRepository Bean` ?

Comment: Do you have another `ParametrosRepository` in a different package? Also why are you trying to work around spring boot? All those annotations and manual configuration aren't really needed.

Comment: No, I don't have another `ParametrosRepository` . I am new in Spring boot so I don't know how optimize the code. If you could help me would be very helpfull.

Comment: In which package is your `Application` class. (I suggest you put it in `almaslab.mapas`.

Comment: it is in `palmaslab.mapas.config` .

Comment: As stated i suggest you place it in `palmaslab.mapas` then you can remove all the annotations (and extends `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`) and only put a `@SpringBootApplication` on it. (You could leave the `@PropertySource(""classpath:email.properties.sample")` although I suggest you move those properties to `application.properties` as well). You can also remove the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` all of those are created for you.

Comment: ok, i will try and update you.

Comment: I can not import  `@SpringBootApplication` annnotation. It seems that no exists.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you on? If that isn't present yet (then it must be an old boot version) use `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` (Just as I put them here, no packages etc.).

Comment: v 1.1.9.RELEASE

Comment: Ah well yes that explains it :). Then add the 3 annotations as mentioned earlier (although I would also suggest an upgrade).

Comment: When I run as a Java Application it works. But same error appears when I run as `gradle bootRun`

Comment: Have you done ` gradle clean build` before `gradle bootRun`?

Comment: It works! thank you. Create an answer to accept it.